# Get the parent tag from html code in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to get the parent of every tag from html code. The result should appear in a DataGridView like this -> **title** **head**, where **title** is the child tag and **head** is the parent tag.
My problem here is how to get the parent tag.

This is my code for parsing the html code:

```
private void btnHTMLParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var CharArray = txtHTML.Text.ToCharArray();
        int next = 0;
        bool flag = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (CharArray[i] == '<')
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                while (flag)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = CharArray[i + next].ToString();
                    if (CharArray[i + next] == '>' && (i + next) <= CharArray.Length - 1)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    next++;
                }

                flag = true;
                next = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code i have another problem. On this line `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = CharArray[i + next].ToString();` appears an error *Index was out of range*. I'm not sure what i have to change. :/

If someone can help me with both problems, I'll really appreciate it. :)

P.S. I cannot use any libraries. That's why i'm not using **HtmlAgilityPack** for parsing the html.

Answer (score 1):

### OutOfRange problem:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i]
```

if each for iteration you add a row, its ok i == last row.

but in yopur case you add the row only if `CharArray[i] == '<'`, so, i > dataGridView1.Rows count.

so instead reffer row index, add the row with the cell value:

```
if (CharArray[i] == '<')
{
    string item = null;

    while (flag)
    {
        item = CharArray[i + next].ToString();
        if (CharArray[i + next] == '>' && (i + next) <= CharArray.Length - 1)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        next++;
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
    flag = true;
    next = 0;
}
```

### the Html analize:

i'm not understand what is the desired result, but try this:

```
private void btnHTMLParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = txtHTML.Text;
    var position = 0;

    while (position < text.Length)
    {
        if (text[position++] == '<')
        {
            StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();
            while (position < text.Length && text[position] != '>')
            {
                tag.Append(text[position]);
                position++; //advance in tag
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(tag.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT seprate logic for clarity:

```
private void btnHTMLParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var tag in GetTagsFromHtml(txtHTML.Text))
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(tag);
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetTagsFromHtml(string text)
{
    var position = 0;

    while (position < text.Length)
    {
        if (text[position++] == '<')
        {
            StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();
            while (position < text.Length && text[position] != '>')
            {
                tag.Append(text[position]);
                position++; //advance in tag
            }
            yield return tag.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @lomed. It works very well. But do you know how can i get the parent of every tag?